# Displaying Custom Polygon on zip code boundaries

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to display zip code boundaries and on that boundaries i want to display custom polygon on that

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Fusion Tables styling</title>
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map, layer;
var tableid = 2996349;
var triangleCoords = [
new google.maps.LatLng(37.2684,-119.956),
new google.maps.LatLng(37.5137,-119.958),
new google.maps.LatLng(37.417, -120.149),
new google.maps.LatLng(37.3957, -119.745)
];
 var bermudaTriangle;
function initialize() {

 var usa=new google.maps.LatLng(37.23032838760389, -118.65234375);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
  center:usa,
  zoom: 4
});


bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
paths: triangleCoords,
strokeColor: '#FF0000',
strokeOpacity: 0.8,
strokeWeight: 2,
fillColor: 'blue',
fillOpacity: 0.35
 });
    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(tableid);
    layer.setQuery("SELECT 'geometry' FROM " + tableid);
    layer.setMap(map);
    bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);


}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
 <body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
 </html>`
```

but it is showing only custom polygon not the boundaries can u share some sample code for displaying the same

Comment: What part of your code do you expect to show zip code boundaries?

Comment: layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(tableid);

Comment: I see both when I use your code, FusionTablesLayer and polygon(of course you must zoom-in, because the Polygon is too small to may be seen on zoom 4).

Comment: i want to display sequence no on polygon so how to do it??